# Selecting multiple items to a data validation field in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple drop down lists on a sheet that sometimes require individuals to input multiple selections within the validated field.  In other words, sometimes they need more than just apples, they need oranges as well; then the data validation field will be apples/oranges.

This code worked until recently, and now for some reason it isn't working, the code is in the "SHEET" not in a module in order for it to work specifically within that sheet.

Here are the specs on the sheet that may be effecting it: the macros are locked (I've tried leaving it unlocked and it didn't fix it).  There are two sheets in the same workbook that have similar code (I tried deleting the script out of the other sheet and it didn't fix it).  There is one other question out there that is pretty close to this but has no answers, so hopefully "Knowing" that this code worked but now doesn't maybe someone can check it out for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 11 And Target.Row < 27 Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & "/" & Newvalue
            Else:
                Target.Value = Oldvalue
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Did it work exactly as you have it? Your `If/Else` statements don't really follow convention - do they indeed work as expected?

Comment: @BruceWayne It works Bruce and the logic is sickening :). I didn't get the logic until I ran the code line by line. Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is on disabling and enabling of events.
I refactored your code and it works fine. See below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Original Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
'To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel

'Refactored error handling...
    On Error GoTo halt
    Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String
    Application.EnableEvents = False '/* disable events here */
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row >= 11 And Target.Row <= 27 Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            'GoTo ExitSub 
        Else
            If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo ExitSub
            Newvalue = Target.Value: Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & "/" & Newvalue
                Else
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '/* enable before exit */
    Exit Sub
halt:
    '/* handle error and communicate to user */
    MsgBox "Opps, encountered error but dismissed it. See details below:" & _
    vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear '/* clear the error */ 
    Resume ExitSub '/* make sure to re-enable events */
End Sub
```

I also removed non-relevant codes. HTH.